# Retrieving data in android from Firebase is skipping frames

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask

Trying to retrieve data from Firebase database is skipping frames. I am trying to iterate through 2000 data nodes and saving it in my SQLite database. Rest the activity does not do much just a GIF is shown while the data is loading on the screen.

```
  databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            loadingKidsData(dataSnapshot, id);
            loadingReadingData(dataSnapshot);
            updateCurrentUserdata(dataSnapshot, id);
            loadingParentsData(dataSnapshot, id);
            databaseReference.removeEventListener(this);
            gotToNewActivity(isParentSignedUp, id);
        };

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723139/wait-firebase-async-retrive-data-in-android/40099900#40099900) but asynchornously retrieving data still results in skipping of frames. What could be the solution to this.

This is how one of the function looks like:

```
    Integer couponcount = dataSnapshot.child("metadata").child("coupons").child("count").getValue(Integer.class);

    if (couponDatabaseHandler.getCouponCount() < couponcount) {
        couponDatabaseHandler.deleteTable();
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> couponSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("coupons").getChildren();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : couponSnapshot) {
            String code = snapshot.child("couponCode").getValue(String.class);
            Integer used = snapshot.child("couponIsUsed").getValue(Integer.class);

            couponDatabaseHandler.addCoupon(new Coupon(snapshot.getKey(), code, used));
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I could load the data any place but the UI thread so that the skipping of frames does not occur

Comment: the data is not getting loaded right?

Comment: No the data is loaded. but it is skipping frames. when I iterate through the snapshot. @PeterHaddad

Comment: remove this `Iterable<DataSnapshot> couponSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("coupons").getChildren();`

Comment: How would I look through the data then ?? @PeterHaddad

Comment: oh yes nevermind I actually thought I saw this `for(DataSnapshot snapshot : couponSnapshot.getChildren()){..}`

Comment: Any ideas on how to make this work ? @PeterHaddad

Comment: I think you have to create a listener for each location. So if you have a node called `Users` and another called `School`, then create a listener for each and get data from each listener. Since I think databaseReference is referencing the root node

Comment: Well I tried that. when I remove everything and just keep a single coupon  snapshot. which has around 1000 nodes in it. It still skips frames @PeterHaddad