# Assigning value to a global variable from FirebaseDatabase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know that is it possible to assign value to a global variable using FirebaseDatabase methods. I know that the FirebaseDatabase methods are asynchronous and executed in background without blocking the main thread. But I am stuck in a case where the value is needed outside the `onDataChange()` method. Here is my java class file:

```
public class DetailActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;

int currentPage = 0;
Timer timer;
final long DELAY_MS = 500;
final long PERIOD_MS = 3000;
CircleIndicator circleIndicator;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private PagerAdapter adapter;

private ArrayList<String> images;
private ArrayList<String> imageDetails;

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private TextView capital, area, population,languages,literacyRate;
private ImageView appbarImageView;
private ExpandableTextView historyTextView;

private String youTubeVideoLink;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    circleIndicator = findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    youTubePlayerView =  findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(BuildConfig.ApiKey, this);

    population = findViewById(R.id.population);
    capital = findViewById(R.id.capital);
    area = findViewById(R.id.area);

    coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.detail_container);
    appbarImageView = findViewById(R.id.app_bar_image);
    historyTextView = findViewById(R.id.expand_text_view);
    literacyRate = findViewById(R.id.literacy_rate);
    languages = findViewById(R.id.languages);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra("State")) {
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(intent.getStringExtra("State"));
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("States").child(intent.getStringExtra("State").trim());
    }



    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable update = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(currentPage == 12) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++,true);
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(update);
        }
    },DELAY_MS,PERIOD_MS);
}

private void readDataFromDatabase(final StatesCallback statesCallback) {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            StateDetails stateDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(StateDetails.class);
            statesCallback.onCallback(stateDetails);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    readDataFromDatabase(new StatesCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(StateDetails stateDetails) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            coordinatorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            capital.setText(stateDetails.getCapital());
            area.setText(stateDetails.getArea());
            population.setText(stateDetails.getPopulation());
            historyTextView.setText(stateDetails.getHistory());
            languages.setText(stateDetails.getLanguages());
            literacyRate.setText(String.valueOf(stateDetails.getLiteracyRate()));
            images = stateDetails.getImages();
            imageDetails = stateDetails.getImageDetails();
            youTubeVideoLink = stateDetails.getYouTubeVideoLink();

            Log.i("youtube video",youTubeVideoLink);
            Picasso.get().load(images.get(0)).into(appbarImageView);
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(DetailActivity.this, images, imageDetails);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            circleIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
            adapter.registerDataSetObserver(circleIndicator.getDataSetObserver());

        }
    });
    if(!b) {
        Log.i("Checking order","video link: "+youTubeVideoLink);
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youTubeVideoLink);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    if(youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(DetailActivity.this,RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST);
    } else {
        String errorMessage = getString(R.string.youTubeErrorMessage)+youTubeInitializationResult;
        Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

  }
}
```

Here's the log details:

```
I/Checking order: video link: null
I/youtube video: QR19-rUVjNQ
```

I want to assign a dynamic video to the YouTubePlayer who's link is stored in the database through the `youTubeVideoLink` string. I have tried the method listed
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723139/wait-firebase-async-retrieve-data-in-android)

But that didn't help. So,Is there any way so that the initialized `youTubeVideoLink` is sent to the `onInitializationSuccess()` method? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply create a global variable and use it's value outside the `onDataChange()` because this methos has an asynchronous behaviour. If you want to use a value that is coming from the database outside the `onDataChange()` method, you have two choices. The first one would be to pass the desired object as argument to a method that is defined in your class or, if you want it in a more complex way, then dive into the asynchronous world of modern API's and see the last part of my answer in this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)**, in which I have explained step by step how you can achieve this. For more information, you can take also a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)**.

**Edit:**

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        StateDetails stateDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(StateDetails.class);
        methodThatDoesSomething(stateDetails); //Method call

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});

private void methodThatDoesSomething(StateDetails stateDetails) {
    //Do what you need to do with your stateDetails object
}
```

Comment: As I have seen in your linked answer that says "Get the data then log it", which means every value so be assigned within onDataChange() and in my case it's not possible, because that data needs to be passed to another method.

Comment: So the first solution, passing the desired object as argument to a method solved your problem?

Comment: Can you explain it with an example or sample code, I am not able to get it as I am new to Android.

Comment: I have to pass the youTubeVideoLink variable to the onInitializationSuccess() method, so it will be the same case as earlier

Comment: In this case, you should use only the second solution which will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried the 2nd method and placed Log inside both the methods but the onInitializationSuccess() is getting executed before the readData() and hence the required value does not reach there.

Comment: You need to call `readData()` inside the `onInitializationSuccess()` method. When calling in this way, you are waiting for the method to finish getting data from the database . Can you share your changed code?

Comment: I have done the same way. I provided the update code together with log details.

Comment: Your code is correct and works as expected and I said that because this statement  `youtube video: QR19-rUVjNQ` is printed out because it is placed inside the `onDataChange()` method. If you want to use it outside like in this line of code: `Log.i("Checking order","video link: "+youTubeVideoLink);` the result will always be `null` as in here: `Checking order: video link: null` and this is because the `asynchronous behavior` of this method, as mentioned also in my answer from that post. Move that `if(!b) {}` also inside the method. It does work, right?

Comment: Yeah, after placing the `if(! b) {} ` inside the method it did work. Thank you so much, Sir. You have been a great help.