# OnCompleteListener block ignored (android studio, java)

Tags: java, android-studio, event-listener

I am trying to get data from firebase (once) so I am using the OnCompleteListener but it seems it is not being triggered

```
private void checkAvailability() {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        String datePath = "Date " + reservationObject.getDate();
        String timePath = "Time " + reservationObject.getTime();
        docRef = db.collection(datePath).document(timePath);
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    //function logic//

                } else {
                    task.getException();
                }
            }
        });
    } // skipping immediately to this line
```

this is the gardle dependency file:

````
 implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0"))
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.6")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.6")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.10.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2")```
````

and this is the firebase collection:
[image]

Tried getting the task.getException(); but the block is completely ignored

Comment: Are you waiting anywhere in the code for the asynchronous code to complete?

Comment: not that I know of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed database to realtime (instead of firestore) and used this answer: [Wait Firebase async retrieve data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723139/wait-firebase-async-retrieve-data-in-android)

Comment: Could have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`addOnCompleteListener` receives a callback as part of it's asynchronous behavior, it will trigger the callback once the operation has been completed.

I noticed your function is synchronous, which means it simply continues to execute and the flow might end before your async operation has been completed.

As I see it, you could either -

- Refactor your code flow to use `Future` of some sort
- Perform the call syncronously

Comment: what possible reason is there that the operation has not been completed already?

Comment: It just might take longer to execute then the rest of your code. For instance, if this is the last operation of an incoming request - the request might end before this code will finish executing.

Asynchronous code is intended to improve our app's performance by using resources (threads) while I/O operations are being performed instead of having them wait for response.

If your code is synchronous - perform the code synchronously, because performing it in an async matter will not make a difference since your app does not support the async paradigm.